# Visualize long texts and edit the content in Processing

Tags: java, processing

i'm trying to recreate this [poster](https://www.behance.net/gallery/12000833/Romeo-Juliet) to understand how to visualize long texts in processing.
For the moment that is what i wrote:

```
import processing.pdf.*;

PFont f;
String txt [];
String myData [];
ArrayList romeopos = new ArrayList();
ArrayList julietpos  = new ArrayList();



void setup() {
  size(600, 800, P2D);
  background(255);
  f = createFont("Garamond", 9);
  txt=loadStrings("test.txt");  


  myData = new String[txt.length];
  myData = txt[0].split(" ");
}



void draw() {
  noLoop();
  fill(50);
  textFont(f);

  for (int i=0; i<myData.length; i++) {

    if ( myData[i].toLowerCase().contains("romeo"))
      romeopos.add(i);
    if ( myData[i].toLowerCase().contains("juliet"))
      julietpos.add(i);
  }

  // text(txt[0], 10, 10, width-20, height-10);
  // println (myData);
}
```

i don't know how to continue, could you help me? the .txt is Romeo and Juliet written in one line.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that you don't know how to continue? What exactly does this code do? What exactly do you want it to do? How exactly are those two things different? Where exactly in the code does its execution differ from what you expect? Could you please include the `test.txt` file? Could you get rid of any extra stuff (like the font file) and post a [mcve] instead?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the steps you'll need to take to recreate that poster in Java with Processing:

- you'll need to open and load a file containing the entire text of the play Romeo and Juliet, to do this I would use the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) Java class
- you should save each line of text as a local variable

  ```
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  ```
- use a yourTextSize global variable to keep track of the textSize() you decide to use.  You will want to multiply this variable by a counter for each line of text:

  ```
  int yPosition = yourTextSize*lineCounter;
  text(line, paddingX, yPosition);
  ```
- now that you have the yPosition of the current line, check the line using a combination of indexOf(String str)
  and indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) methods of [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the character index of all the "Romeo" strings.  To make figuring out the x coordinates of a "Romeo" character index easier, use a monospace font. Store all of the Romeo points in an ArrayList. Find all the "Juliet" indexes the same way and store the Juliet points in separate ArrayList.  Use a Point Java object to store these points.
- finally, it appears in the poster that every instance of Romeo is linked by a red line to every instance of Juliet.  Iterate through the Romeo point ArrayList in a for loop, each time drawing a line using Processing's line() to all the points in the Juliet array list.

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < Romeo.length(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < Juliet.length(); j++) {
          line(Romeo.get(i).getX, Romeo.get(i).getY, Juliet.get(j).getX, Juliet.get(j).getY);
      }
  }
  ```

My advice in tackling this project is to start small; use 1/16th of the play until you've nearly finished the program.  Simply rendering the entire text of Romeo and Juliet will take some time if you use a reasonably sized font.  You'll need to make the size(width, height); of your program enormous to fit the whole play.  You seem to be just starting to learn how to code with Processing, perhaps try working on a few simpler projects before tackling this one?  Please approve of my answer if you appreciate the time I've put into it :).  If you have any general conceptual questions about my answer I'll be happy to follow up but I think if you have any specific followup questions about the classes or API's mentioned that aren't already answered on StackOverflow then you should ask them in another post.